# Living in the sukka

Tags: sukkah

Why should one bring the nicest utensils in the Sukka?
Was the first Sukka [in Sukkot] in the midbar not different?
Is the sukka not a dira arai where we should dwell as a remembrance with big simcha and ha-karat ha-tov?
But what does it has to do with the nicest vessels etc [ve-anvehu??]

Comment: Who said they kept Succot in the wilderness? They didn't keep Pesach and they stayed in the Succos all year long.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, it is learned from תשבו כעין תדורו, see Succah 26.

It means that the Succah becomes the main place and the apartment secondary. So if one has two sets of utensils, he takes the nicest one to the Succah, just as he would do in his main apartment.

As you mentioned this rule is in addition to the rule of זה אלי ואנוהו.

Answer (score -1):

''I cant have the entire thing for myself then i don't need it at all ''Does that statement sound familiar A happy and grateful person enjoys his nice dishes and cutlery even when he barely has a roof on top of him OR WHEN ALL HE HAS IS סכך ON TOP OF HIS HEAD.    P.S. THE NICE DISHES SHALL BE THERE BECAUSE OF SIMCHAS YOM TOV OR AS YOUR REGULAR WAY OF LIVING ,AND ON TOP OF THAT HASHEM TELLS US 'ENJOY THIS MEAL IMMENSELY EVEN WITHOUT YOUR REGULAR ROOF TOP' ,WHICH WILL BRING OUT YOUR TRUE SIMCHA ON ZEMAN SIMCHOSAINU .

Comment: Consider clarifying. Are you suggesting that the reason for the halakha regarding one's dishes in the sukkah is to teach the lesson of appreciating whatever one has? Do you have a source, or is this your own idea?

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT - we can hear you quite well